# No such property: nexusUsername for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle

I am trying to add gradle project to Eclipse, but this error have corupted.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/user/Downloads/AndroidSlidingUpPanel-master/maven_push.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':demo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':library'.
> No such property: nexusUsername for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

and the build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-        projects/modules.
buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
 }
}

 def isReleaseBuild() {
 return version.contains("SNAPSHOT") == false
 } 

allprojects {
version = VERSION_NAME
group = GROUP

  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

If someone have any ideas to resolve this, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 3):

commenting the lines 21 to 23 of maven_push.gradle seems to solve the problem

```
repository(url: sonatypeRepositoryUrl) {
   authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
}
```

happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the build possible even if somebody hasn't added a `nexusUsername` and if you have a proper default, you can use

```
if (!hasProperty('nexusUsername')) {
    ext.nexusUsername = ''
}
```

to your build script.

Answer (score 1):

create a file ~/.gradle/gradle.properties with the following contents:

```
nexusUsername=
nexusPassword=
```

Hope it will resolved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message indicates, `maven_push.gradle` (line 22) refers to a property named `nexusUsername`, which however isn't defined. Chances are that the build assumes that you have such a property defined in your `~/.gradle/gradle.properties`.